# Как перевести массив в pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

Задача состоит в том, чтобы скачать информацию с сайта, на который требуется ввод пароля и логина.

```
import requests
import pandas as pd 
data1 = {'login':'my_login', 'password':'my_password'}
url = 'https://sss.krasilnikov.spb.ru/classcl/2019-2/data'
r = requests.post(url, data=data1)
ways = r.text.replace('\n',' ').replace(' ','').split('\n')
ways
```

1). Как перевести массив(ways) с ссылками в pandas.DataFrame?

Comment: Прочитайте пожалуйста: [Как задать хороший вопрос?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060) и постарайтесь сформулировать один вопрос, привести пример входных и выходных данных и ваши попытки решения...

Comment: Ответ будет целиком и полностью зависеть от того в каком виде представлены данные на входе и от того как должен будет выглядеть DataFrame на выходе...

Answer (score 1):

Вот несколько примеров создания DataFrame из массивов / списков:

```
In [55]: pd.DataFrame([1,2,3])
Out[55]:
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3

In [56]: pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3], [4,5,6]])
Out[56]:
   0  1  2
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6

In [57]: pd.DataFrame(list('abcd'))
Out[57]:
   0
0  a
1  b
2  c
3  d

In [58]: pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(5,3)), columns=list('abc'))
Out[58]:
   a  b  c
0  9  1  1
1  2  7  6
2  8  5  4
3  3  4  0
4  6  1  6
```

выбирайте... ;)

Comment: Использовал 3 способ и на выходе получил dataframe, но он разделили массив на элементы не той длины. То есть получилась не таблица с ссылками, а таблица с буквами и цифрами. В исходных данных между ссылками есть разделение в виде запятой, почему python их не замечает?)

Comment: @user325883, если вы хотите получить решение, которое будет работать для ваших данных, то потрудитесь привести в вопросе небольшой пример входных данных и то, что вы хотите получить на выходе. Ещё раз советую внимательно прочитать вопросы и ответы по ссылкам из комментария, особенно по последней ссылке.